# netbeans + svn + deployment workflow

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

I have almost no experience in using netbeans and svn so please correct me gently if I am wrong. I come from using python/vim/git so workflow wise is foreign to me.

Currently, I used the Netbeans' svn plugin to checkout my project from a remote repository. The project has several components like webservices, and also a swing client and of the business logics.

Assuming that I need to work with the web services and the swing client, do I create separate projects for each, and import the project as references?

Finally, currently I'm using netbeans to test the webapp on the local glassfish server. How do I deploy on a remote test server so that my team mates can use and test the web app?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. For the first part `do I create separate projects for each, and import the project as references`, you ***should*** never have to do that if the overall project is setup correctly already in SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the seperate components are a part of the same project in svn then, no, you should only create one project in netbeans. Check out the project from svn and once netbeans has checked out the project it should prompt you to create a netbeans project when it does select project from existing sources, follow the wizard steps and your project will be created. You will have to import any external jars needed by the project that has been checked out into the newly created project in netbeans. NOTE: Netbenas will create a build.xml file for the newly created project so be sure that you do not commit that build.xml file into the repository unless it's needed.

To setup a remote server in netbeans go to tools->servers, select add server, select the server type(glassfish, tomcat, etc) then enter the pertinent information for the server using the wizard.

Comment: hi currently the creator of my project's svn created that such that the trunk root is just in class packages folder , and there is no concept of project files yet. which is why i am confused over this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First question "Assuming that I need to work with the web services and the swing client, do I create separate projects for each, and import the project as references?"

It really depends on your architecture - how coupled are those components. It's also important what packaging system do you use? For example if you use Maven you can easily modulate the project and define dependencies between the modules. Check out [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects) for details. I am referring to maven as it's build-in in Netbeans.

Regarding your testing you basically have 2 options:

a) expose your glassfish to your buddies

b) package and deploy your project remotely - this really cannot be given straight answer - depends on your infrastructure, where's the remote server, how big the deployment package is, how the application server behaves regarding hot deployments etc.

I suggest try the first option.

Answer (score 0):

**SVN** helps you to keep the project in several versions in the repository.
You can always checkout from repository.
once you checked out, you will be using the project from a saved directory somewhere in your local machine.
Now, you can keep on developing the project, at the same time your friends can also keep doing that, and whenever you think you have done enough changes or development then after verifying your own copy of the project, you can commit the changes to repository.
After committing the changes will be visible in the repository to everyone, and hence anyone can access this updated version of the project residing in the repository.
**Note** that the earlier version will not be deleted, unless you do so.
Your friend can also checkout a copy of the project from the repository and they can merge it with their existing ones, and they can also commit the changes.
and at the same time, you can ask your friend to check your developed code by checking out the project and deploying on their local server.

I hope it gives you a better picture.